# WebSocket compatibility with GopherJS

Tags: go, websocket, gopherjs

Looking for some general guidance on how to implement a WebSocket client in a way that works on both native Go execution platforms and through GopherJS.

It appears that GopherJS has two WebSocket libraries, one at [`gopherjs/websocket`](https://github.com/gopherjs/websocket) and one at [`goxjs/websocket`](https://github.com/goxjs/websocket). It seems that `goxjs/websocket` is "isomorphic", meaning it should work in GopherJS while remaining API-compatible with `golang.org/x/net/websocket`. That would provide compatibility in both execution environments, which is fine, but I'm not sure if it's the best solution. `gopherjs/websocket` doesn't appear to work outside of the browser execution environment, so it's a non-starter.

The most recommended WebSocket implementation for native Go apps seems to be [`gorilla/websocket`](https://github.com/gorilla/websocket) at the moment. I'd like to use this as it seems to have a good API and it seems rather fully-featured. I *can* successfully run `gopherjs build` if I import `gorilla/websocket`, but I'm concerned that it will fail in the JavaScript environment, or that it will be compiled down into JavaScript that doesn't use the browser's implementation of the WebSocket API.

I'm not seeing much guidance on which library is appropriate for which scenario, so hoping this can help compare and contrast and provide the direction necessary to make a good choice.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any guidance on what you should do, but can share these facts:

The gorilla/websocket package is an implementation of the Websocket protocol on TCP connections. Because browser applications cannot access TCP connections directly, the gorilla/websocket package will not run in the browser.

There's a difference in the models presented by gorilla/websocket package and the gopherjs/websocket packages. The WebSocket protocol is message-based and the gorilla/websocket package exposes an API around messages. The gopherjs/websocket provides bindings that make the message-based WebSocket protocol look like a stream of bytes. Messages are not exposed in the gopherjs/websocket API.

The x/net/websocket package is all but abandoned. There are [long standing issues with protocol compliance](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/7632) that have not been addressed.